# Close a single tab in browser using windows application c# /vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to open an `URL` in browser from my windows application using `Process.start()`. Instead of close the whole browser window, I only want to close the tab that created by my windows application.

I tried `Process.Kill()` but it closes the whole browser window.

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Users expect to "own" browser windows and tabs. As soon as you've launched your URL, you should forget about it. You certainly shouldn't *kill* a tab where the user may have freely navigated to other pages, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Though I understand why it does so (IIS Express), Visual Studio seems to think by default that it's allowed to close Chrome after I stop debugging, though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, there is no way of closing a **specific tab** in the browser using VB.NET or C# (or any server side code for that matter). The only way of doing this is using Javascript in your opened web page. If you created this page, you can write a client side command which closes the tab. Once you launched a website using server side code, controls is passed to the browser itself. The only thing you can do is close the browser process completely.

As a side note, Some browsers, like Google Chrome, keep a speprate windows process for each tab. So you could track which process was opened, and close it by its `PID`. But this solution would not work for other browsers. If you want to force the user to launch your website via Google Chrome, you could launch `chrome.exe` with a start argument of the URL you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing is impossible, everything is extremely complex.

Generally speaking, there is no way of closing a specific tab of a browser.

However a "never to do" way of do this could be:

- Open the URL with a specific browser (Chrome, for example);
- Make the browser (the `<browser>.exe` process) the active Window (using WinAPI);
- Send a key combination to select the desidered tab (it should already be selected);
- Send a key combination to close the tab (`CTRL + W`, for example)

Just an idea..