# How to close a browser tab when clicking on a Button? Visual Basic 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I need some help in the following situation, I am creating an Agenda in VB.net (visual basic 2019), in my Form I have a Button1 that when clicking it opens a certain web page in a tab in the chrome browser, however I need to do the opposite, that when clicking on a Button2 it closes only the tab opened by Button1 without closing the browser.

```
Public Class FrmAgenda
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim weblink As String
        weblink = "www.google.com"
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", weblink)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close a single tab in browser using windows application c# /vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247162/close-a-single-tab-in-browser-using-windows-application-c-sharp-vb-net)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/790966/Hosting-and-Changing-Controls-in-Other-Application It has everything you need to explor other apps, find controls, click buttons etc. Very interesting project.